# Knockout.js URL Encoding

Tags: url, knockout.js, url-encoding

I have some Knockout.js code on my page that produces a list of downloadable files depending on the selected value of a drop down list - the source of the downloads are in a SQL db and I just store the physical file name - the list is returned to the page in Json format via an ASP.Net MVC Controller Action. The pertinent Knockout code is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function DDLViewModel() {

        var self = this;
        self.ddlDim1 = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedDim1 = ko.observable();
        self.selectedDim1.subscribe(FetchVariant);

        //default values from Model
        self.PDFs = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PDFs)));

        function FetchVariant() {
            if (self.selectedDim1())
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetVariant")', // we are calling json method
                    dataType: 'json',
                    // here we get value of selected dim.
                    data: { productId: @Model.Product.ProductID,
                        Dim1: self.selectedDim1()
                    },
                    success: function (variant) {
                        // variant contains the JSON formatted variant data passed from the controller
                        var newpv = [];
                        newpv.push(variant);
                        self.PDFs(newpv[0].PDFs);
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        //alert('Failed to retrieve variant.' + ex);
                        self.PDFs(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PDFs)));
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //not selected so reset all values back to Model
                self.PDFs(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PDFs)));
            }
        }


    }

    ko.applyBindings(new DDLViewModel);
})

<div data-bind="visible: PDFs().length">
    <h3>Downloads</h3>
    <!-- ko foreach: PDFs -->
    <p><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/artwork/ProdPDF/' + FileName }, text: Title" target="_blank"></a></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The issue I have is that the filename is not being encoded so any filenames with say an ampersand character in isn't working. Is there a way to encode the url/filename inline in the Knockout code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

```
<p><a data-bind="attr: { href: '/artwork/ProdPDF/' + encodeURIComponent(FileName) }, text: Title" target="_blank"></a></p>
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent() did the trick!